# PHP Session Class return values

Tags: session-variables, php

i have a simplet session class (below):

```
class Session{

    public static function init(){
            @session_start();
        }

    public static function set($key, $value){
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($key){
      if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
        return $_SESSION[$key];
       } else if(empty($key)){
        return $_SESSION;
       }

    }

    public static function destroy(){
        session_destroy();
    }

 }
```

To set a single session value i use

```
  Session::set(Name, value);
```

To set a multiple session value i use

```
  Session::set(Name, array(name, value....));
```

Then to simply retrieve the session i require i use:

```
  Session::get(Name);
```

Now my problem is that when i can set multi dimension values, i cannot actually get them with the current get function above. SO how can i re-structure my get($key) so that it not only returns a single request but also any request

```
  Session::set('joe', 'bloggs');
  Session::set('beth', array('age'=>'21','height'=>'5.5ft'));
```

So for instance  again I get a single session value EG Joe:

```
    Session::get('joe');
```

Then if i want to get beth's details i can assign the session value to a var and then access the inner details like so:

```
   $age = Session::get('beth');
   $age['age']
```

But would it be possible to reconstruct my get method so i can do:

```
  Session::get('beth','age');
```

Or would it be best to stick to what i am currently doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update your `get` method to this:

```
public static function get($key, $item = NULL){
    if (isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
        if(isset($item) && isset($_SESSION[$key][$item])) {
            return $_SESSION[$key][$item];
        }

        return $_SESSION[$key];
    } 

    return NULL; //not found
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
Session::get('joe'); // returns array
Session::get('joe', 'age'); // returns joe's age
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what you need**

```
Session::set('joe', 'bloggs');
Session::set('beth', array('age' => '21','height' => '5.5ft','ball' => array("A" => "blue","B" => "Green")));

var_dump(Session::get("beth", "age")); // returns 21
var_dump(Session::get("beth", "ball", "A")); // returns blue
```

**Your class modified**

```
class Session {

    private static function init() {
        if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
            session_start();
    }

    public static function set($key, $value) {
        self::init();
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function get() {
        self::init();
        $args = func_get_args(); // Get all arguments
        $items = $_SESSION; // create a tempoary version of $_SESSION aarray
        foreach ( $args as $ndx ) {
            // Take Item and override with Subitem
            $items = isset($items[$ndx]) ? $items[$ndx] : null;
        }
        return $items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice way of using the `$_SESSION` array and override it with the first found match and then matching it again with the next arg. But you'll should add some comments to make the code clear and readable for the non-PHP-experts.

Comment: Never knew that was not clear ... updated with simple comments

Comment: So @Sven when you mention this being a nice way would this be a better method than the one demo'd ? It's a little bigger for the same effect but are they identical or better

Comment: @SimonDavies The are both good answers. But you need to look at what you need. If you are going/wanting to use it as `Session::get(arg, arg2, ..)` then use this one, otherwise keep it simple. ;)

Comment: @SimonDavies `Sven` answer is only valid if you are using two argument .. but if you would end up using more than 2 argument then use this ...

Comment: @Baba Not a problem i understand that bit and appreciate your answer as i know i will use that soon as well thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be careful. That may be confusing to some of us, as in some frameworks, the second parameter in a getter means a *default value*:

```
Session::get('key', 'defaultValue');
```

`defaultValue` would be returned if key is not present.

Probably not the best solution, but you could convert everything you `set` to a special class (maybe called `KeyValue` or whatever) and, when you use get, you could return either the value of the key **OR** another `KeyValue` object, with an implementation of `get()`, doing the same once again, returning the value **OR** another `KeyValue`. That way, you would be able to method chain in a rather cool way:

```
Session::get('beth')->get('age')
```

Answer (score 0):

Function like this could be used with unlimited number of keys:

```
public static function get()
{
    $array = $_SESSION;
    $keys = func_get_args();
    foreach($keys as $key)
    {
        if(isset($array[$key]))
            $array = $array[$key];
        else
            return FALSE; // or it could return array()
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Core PHP or other any framework of PHP for showing all the data in SESSION

```
   print_r($_SESSION);
   public function setSessionValue($session_name, $session_value){
         $_SESSION[$session_name] = $session_value;
   }

   public function getSessionValue($session_name){
         return $_SESSION[$session_name];
   }
```